# Two layers have the same projection but different units

Tags: qgis

Two of my layers aren't aligning even though they're in the same area and use the same projection system. I am not sure why they won't align but I think it is maybe because they have different units for some reason.

The first layer is a polygon shapefile I downloaded from ReGrid. I haven't been able to find out what their CRS is but I am fairly sure it's NAD83 Michigan South because that's what it auto-projected to when I opened it in QGIS:

[image]

The second layer is a CSV of points in the same region that I imported and projected to match the first layer's CRS:
[image]

Comment: Your csv seem to be in geographic coordinates system (look at the extent), you need set the proper gsc and then reproject it (or let qgis do on the fly reprojection)

Comment: What may have happened is that the CSV layer was assigned the EPSG:2253 projection, rather than reprojected to it. You can set it to WGS84 by right-clicking the layer > Layer CRS > Set Layer CRS. Hopefully that will position it properly and from there you can reproject it to EPSG:2253.

Comment: I just checked and the first coordinate of the extent (using WGS84) is in Ann Arbor, a town near to Detroit.

Comment: @Matt Thanks! I always forget that assigning a layer a projection isn't the same as actually projecting it. That fixed the problem.